# Does the Qur'an state that Jesus was crucified?

Tags: quran, prophet-isa

I am new to Islam and wondering whether or not the Qur'an states that Jesus was crucified on a cross.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Direct Answer:

Qur'an does talk about it:

> وَقَوْلِهِمْ إِنَّا قَتَلْنَا الْمَسِيحَ عِيسَى ابْنَ مَرْيَمَ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ وَمَا قَتَلُوهُ وَمَا صَلَبُوهُ وَلَٰكِن شُبِّهَ لَهُمْ ۚ وَإِنَّ الَّذِينَ اخْتَلَفُوا فِيهِ لَفِي شَكٍّ مِّنْهُ ۚ مَا لَهُم بِهِ مِنْ عِلْمٍ إِلَّا اتِّبَاعَ الظَّنِّ ۚ وَمَا قَتَلُوهُ يَقِينًا
>
> *Sahih International*
>
> And [for] their saying, "Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah ." And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him; but [another] was made to resemble him to them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they did not kill him, for certain.
>
> [[Surat An-Nisā':157]](http://quran.com/4/157)

That is, the Qur'an says that it was made to look like he was crucified however he was not.  It was someone else who took his place.

---

## Side Notes / Points of interest:

Some [Christian Gnostics also believe](http://ezinearticles.com/?The-Gospel-of-Judas---Jesus-Was-Not-Crucified&id=179434) he was not Crucified:

**The Second Treatise of The Great Seth**

> It was another...who drank the gall and the vinegar; it was not I...
>   it was another Simon, who bore the cross on his shoulder. It was
>   another upon whom they placed the crown of thorns. But I was rejoicing
>   in the height (the hills) over... their error. And I was laughing at
>   their ignorance. (for thinking it was I who they were crucifying)

AND **The Gospel of Judas** never mentions the event at all!  Quite surprising considering Judas' (يهوذا) role in Jesus' life.

FYI, The Christian Gnostic Gospel of Judas pre date the 4 Gospels kept in the New Testament.

---

Logically, it would be really hard to know if was crucified - however if that is what you believe, it's your belief.  What is important is that we love God, the single creator God, the God of Abraham/אַבְרָהָם/Ibrahim/إبراهيم‎.  Remember that as the name of Abraham changes in each language, God, YHWH, and Allah refer to the one single God - which some of us worship differently.

Comment: Frankly, your "points of interest" don't really help with the answer and just add bias to your answer. The question asked what does Islam say about crucifixion; not what other religions say about it.

Answer (score 5):

This is what Quran says about Jesus PBUH:

> And [for] their saying, "Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus,
>   the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah." And they did not kill him,
>   nor did they crucify him; but [another] was made to resemble him to
>   them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They
>   have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they
>   did not kill him, for certain. http://tanzil.net/#4:157

According to [Shia Islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia_Islam) he was not crucified but was raised to sky  and will save humanity from Dajjal and Jesus PBUH will pray behind Mahdi AJ. But God changed shape of his hypocrite companions to the shape of Jesus PBUH to punish him. So he was arrested and curified instead of Jesus PBUH. shia Muslims believe Jesus PBUH is alive but  like 12th Imam of shia (Imam Mahdi AJ. who is in occultation currently) and they both will return at ends of times. Hided from public but not from all.

Also a movie about life of Jesus PBUH is made based on believes of Shia Islam that watching is useful about learning view of Shia Islam regarding this issue.

**References and further info:**

[Jesus through Shiite Narrations](http://www.al-islam.org/jesus_shiite_narrations/)

[The Messiah (2007 film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Messiah_%282007_film%29)

[Al-Imam al-Mahdi, The Just Leader of Humanity](http://www.al-islam.org/mahdi/nontl/Toc.htm)

Answer (score 2):

This is the proof from the Holy Qur'an that Jesus (PBUH) was not crucified

**Surat An-Nisā' (The Women)**

**4:157**

> [image]

And [for] their saying, "Indeed, we have killed the Messiah, Jesus, the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah ." And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him; but [another] was made to resemble him to them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they did not kill him, for certain.

Sahih International